# android getting the activity object of the current foreground activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

i'm building a chat client and i want to be able to get the current running activity object (not just his name).

i need this in order to get this activity's intent object to check if there were any Extras..

is it possible to do so ?

i have this code:

```
ActivityManager mActivityManager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
List<ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo> RunningTask = mActivityManager.getRunningTasks(1);
ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo ar = RunningTask.get(0);
return ar.topActivity.toString();
```

but it only gives my the name of it, and i need it's object..

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you can't access the object directly this way as it would be a security breach : you could just access any (as in not just your) running activity this way and interact with them or kill them to your liking.

Maybe you should review your design.

The first cheap hack that come to my mind and that is close to what you did is to maintain a static map of all the activity you launch with the associated name as key to get the activity thanks to it's name.